# convert a column typeof list with metacharacter "|"

Tags: r, multiple-columns, tidyr

I have this matrix that I want to convert into a column with the counts of each cell that matches its respective column that allows me to quantify the quantity of each type of car.

[image: that's is data raw]

```
library(tidyverse)


colsgroup <- read_csv("colsgroup.csv")
typeof(colsgroup)

colsgroup$car <-  gsub("[|]", ",", colsgroup$car) %>%  
  as.data.frame() %>%  
  separate(1L,
           into = c("car_1","car_2","car_3","car_4","car_5","car_6","car_7","car_8"), sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character)
```

this is the result

[image: result my code]

this is what i want to get, much like to use pivot_wider

[image: this is i want]

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example input data

Comment: Could you please use `dput()` for your sample data? We can't demonstrate a solution on a picture.

Comment: Followup your current code with `mutate(across(everything(), ~ +!is.na(.)))`. (BTW, `mutate_all` has been superseded by `mutate(across(everything(), ...))`.)

Comment: dput(colsgroup)
structure(list(car = c("car_2", "car_3", "car_7|car_8|car_2|car_4", 
"car_3|car_6|car_1|car_5|car_2|car_4", "car_5|car_3", "car_6"
), scorecard = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(car = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), scorecard = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x0000025781d10a40>, class = c("spec_tbl_df",

Comment: sigue...."tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier with `dummy_cols`

```
library(fastDummies)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dummy_cols(colsgroup, 'car', split= "\\|") %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_remove(.x, "car_"), starts_with('car_'))%>%   
   select(car, scorecard, order(readr::parse_number(names(.)[-(1:2)])) + 2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 10
  car                                 scorecard car_1 car_2 car_3 car_4 car_5 car_6 car_7 car_8
  <chr>                                   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 car_2                                       1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
2 car_3                                       1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
3 car_7|car_8|car_2|car_4                     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1
4 car_3|car_6|car_1|car_5|car_2|car_4         1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
5 car_5|car_3                                 1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
6 car_6                                       1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `separate_rows` function instead of `separate`, then convert long table to wide.

```
library(tidyverse)

colsgroup <- read_csv("colsgroup.csv") %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% # remember the original row
  separate_rows(car, sep = "\\|") %>%
  spread(car, scorecard)
```

Comment: If you replace `spread` (superseded) with `pivot_wider(rowid, names_from = car, values_from = scorecard, values_fill = 0)`, it'll be more updated and fill with 0s.

Comment: `spread` works the same way with `fill = 0` argument. I agree that it's superseded by `pivot_wider` but not depricated (yet?) and sometime easier to use (don't have to name all the arguments).